# Are props.render and props.children equal?

Tags: reactjs

I can't find a distinction between **props.render** and **props.children**, so I'm starting to believe that they achieve the same thing BUT in different ways.

Is this a correct assumption? If not; how are they different (beside how they are implemented), and when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[render-props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) can address your questions.

`children` is part of the Top-level API, meaning, it is intrinsic to a react component. The `children` prop can be just about anything react can render, typically an element or array of elements, but can be a function similar to a "render prop".

The "render" prop, however, is not intrinsic, it can be anything really... so long as it is a function.

[Using props other then render](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render)

> It’s important to remember that just because the pattern is called
>   “render props” you don’t have to use a prop named render to use this
>   pattern. In fact, any prop that is a function that a component uses to
>   know what to render is technically a “render prop”.